# RavenDB and MsSql inside same transaction scope results in WebException

Tags: sql-server, ravendb, transactionscope, system.net.webexception

In response to another question on stackoverflow [RavenDB does not play nicely with Transaction Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724614/ravendb-does-not-play-nicely-with-transaction-scope) i have created a test case where i isolate my transactions for storing and reading. In my test case i am making a call to a raven document store and a mssql database within the same transaction. But i get a Web Exception. Any ideas why or how to solve it.
Below is my code

```
    private static string con = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=.";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            additemtosql();
        }
        Console.WriteLine((itemSqlCount() == 0));

        using (var mDocumentStore = new DocumentStore())
        {
            mDocumentStore.ParseConnectionString("Url=http://localhost:8081");
            mDocumentStore.Initialize();
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                additemtoravendb(mDocumentStore);

                Console.WriteLine((itemSqlCount() == 0));

                scope.Complete();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(itemRavenCount(mDocumentStore) == 1);
        }

    }
    private static void additemtoravendb(IDocumentStore mDocumentStore)
    {
        using (var session = mDocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var dog = new Dog()
            {
                Age = 10,
                BirthDay = DateTime.Now,
                Breed = "Dalmation",
                Name = "Fluffy"
            };
            session.Store(dog);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static int itemRavenCount(IDocumentStore mDocumentStore)
    {
        using (var session = mDocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var dogs = session.Query<Dog>().ToList();
            return dogs.Count();
        }
    }
    private static void additemtosql()
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO RECORDS_TEXT VALUES (1, 'XX', 'XX') ";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(con))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine((itemSqlCount() == 1));
        }
    }
    private static int itemSqlCount()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(con))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECORDS_TEXT";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                var count = reader.GetInt32(0);
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am well aware that i start with a transaction scope and then i don't complete it, it's what i am testing. Not completing a transaction should roll it back, if i'm right. I want to test a failed transaction, and then a successful one.

And the reason why i'm calling ravendb and mssql inside the same transaction here is because i am simulating what might happen with nested transactions where one call might be to sql and another to raven, without knowing the other call was even made.

Comment: And here is the stack trace of the error:
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseBytes() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 188
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPromoteTransaction(Guid fromTxId, String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 1180
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass7b.<PromoteTransaction>b__7a(String u) in c:\Builds\RavenDB

Comment: Look at the actual request in Fiddler. It will tell you what the error is.
But I think that this is already fixed in the latest builds.

Comment: Yes, updating RavenDB worked and did the trick. Thanks for answering.